# Loading huge amount of data in OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have been working on a `PoC` to load a huge amount of data ~ 350k-500k but I haven't been successful so far. I tried loading `JSON` then converting them to `ol3` features (failed at 130k) then I used `GeoJSON` where I could load 150k data but zoom-in , zoom-out makes the map crash. Also, I have been using Clusters. How do I get around the problem? I can't use `WMS` since my only source of data is a `JSON` whose format can be modified.

INFO: The `GeoJSON` I prepared is roughly 40MB. I was thinking of using `gzip` compression. Would it help me in anyway?

Comment: 40MB in any web browser is going to choke it. for a solution look at geojson vt (vector tiles) https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-vt

Comment: @Mapperz thank you for your reply but my only issue is that the map library should be completely opensource regardless of where it is being used. So I guess OpenLayers is my only option. Noway I can get it working right?

Answer (score 2):

The solution that @Mapperz is suggesting outputs a format that can be used across the web, i.e. protocol buffers. Vector tiles, which geojson-vt outputs are made of protobufs, which are a binary format used to serialize data. This means that they can be way faster and lighter than JSON, for example, a text form of serialization. This is what google has been using for a while with google maps and is the reason why there maps were always so fast and you could never sniff out the geojson doing it.  Essentially make vector tiles either via a node package like geojson-vt or use the node tool tilelive. I am successfully making vector tiles from all my postgis/shapefile data and am serving them using my own vector tile server in combination with mapbox streaming layers, which are totally free. This is high level so I will try to make a simple example of all this flow when I have time.

Comment: @avneesh-srivastava I have not used it but I would suggest looking into the python library togeojsontiles: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/togeojsontiles/0.1.2 It uses tippecanoe to convert geojson to an xyz slippy map format which can be used in openlayers.